# Usage of the ternary "?:" operator with functions listening to click events

Tags: javascript

I've recently been doing some mods to some old code I've been maintaining for a couple of years now.

As part of a wider set of scripts using YAHOO YUI 2.2 (yes, that old) for dialog-style panels, I have a function that listens to click events on 3 buttons in a given panel set:

```
addFooListeners = function (panelType) {

    YAHOO.util.Event.addListener("show" + panelType, "click", showFoo, eval(ns + ".panel_" + panelType), true);
    YAHOO.util.Event.addListener("hide" + panelType, "click", hideFoo, eval(ns + ".panel_" + panelType), true);
    YAHOO.util.Event.addListener("commit" + panelType, "click", commitFoo, eval(ns + ".panel_" + panelType), true);

}
```

This code is the result of a number of panels/dialogs having near identical behaviour.

For this round of development I've needed to add the ability to do things a little differently from time to time, so I added an object, `overrides` which allows me to point the `show`, `hide` and `commit` actions elsewhere.  I came up with the following:

```
addFooListeners = function (panelType, overrides) {

    var handlers = {
        show: ( overrides != null ? ( overrides.show != null ? overrides.show : showFoo ) : showFoo ),
        hide: ( overrides != null ? ( overrides.hide != null ? overrides.hide : hideFoo ) : hideFoo ),
        commit: ( overrides != null ? ( overrides.commit != null ? overrides.commit : commitFoo ) : commitFoo )
    }

    YAHOO.util.Event.addListener("show" + panelType, "click", handlers.show, eval(ns + ".panel_" + panelType), true);
    YAHOO.util.Event.addListener("hide" + panelType, "click", handlers.hide, eval(ns + ".panel_" + panelType), true);
    YAHOO.util.Event.addListener("commit" + panelType, "click", handlers.commit, eval(ns + ".panel_" + panelType), true);
}
```

As you can see I'm enforcing default behaviour unless an appropriate attribute in the `overrides` object is set with another function (named or anonymous).

Is there a cleaner / more readable way to concisely setup the `handlers` object?  The nested ternary seems to my eyes to be cluttering things a bit but other approaches like `if ( overrides != null ) { ... }` seem just as messy.

Comment: My personal opinion is that the `?` ternary operator is worth using only when it's not nested.  In your case it just makes the code more unreadable and unmaintainable.

Comment: I like formatting nested ternary operators so they read like multiple questions: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/6562/8891

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Let's do some fixing. First, this is how you pass optional (non-boolean) parameters in JS (the Good Way<sup>tm</sup>):

```
addFooListeners = function (panelType, handlers) {
    handlers        = handlers        || {};
    handlers.show   = handlers.show   || showFoo;
    handlers.hide   = handlers.hide   || hideFoo;
    handlers.commit = handlers.commit || commitFoo;
```

The above can be rewritten in a neater way using jQuery (not sure what the name of YUI equivalent to `extend` is):

```
handlers = $.extend({
    show  : showFoo, 
    hide  : hideFoo, 
    commit: commitFoo
}, handlers || {})
```

Now, using eval for this code is criminal. Say the object `ns` refers to is `module`, then you can do this instead of `eval`:

```
YAHOO.util.Event.addListener("show" + panelType, "click", handlers.show, module["panel_" + panelType], true);
YAHOO.util.Event.addListener("hide" + panelType, "click", handlers.hide, module["panel_" + panelType], true);
YAHOO.util.Event.addListener("commit" + panelType, "click", handlers.commit, module["panel_" + panelType], true);
```

Now, as you can see, you are assigning a lot of events in a similar fashion. Did you think of defining an addPanelListener function within your function?

```
function addPanelListener (event, panelType, handler) {
    YAHOO.util.Event.addListener(event + panelType, "click", handler, module["panel_" + panelType], true);
} 

addPanelListener("show"  , panelType, handlers.show);
addPanelListener("hide"  , panelType, handlers.hide);
addPanelListener("commit", panelType, handlers.commit):
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: +1 for flagging use of eval as criminal :) I find "the Good Way" more readable than the jQuery way.

Comment: Using `eval` in my company pretty much guarantees a 3-hour _basics of javascript_ meeting with me :)

Comment: aaah good old "the-first-one-is-free" `eval`.  Much like a drug pusher.  I cringe every time I see that in my code (especially the code I post here ;-).

Comment: @glebm can you elaborate on what makes "The Good Way" the good way?

Comment: Of course. It is easily readable, less error-prone, and, as a bonus, it's faster. :)

Comment: Always welcome!

Answer (score 7):

It looks like you can reduce that ternary a bit by using && like this:

```
var handlers = {
    show:  ( overrides != null && overrides.show != null ? overrides.show : showFoo ),
    hide:  ( overrides != null && overrides.hide != null ? overrides.hide : hideFoo ),
    commit: ( overrides != null && overrides.commit != null ? overrides.commit : commitFoo )
}
```

I'm not too familiar with javascript but does the function parameter have to be checked against null? Like for example, can you further shorten the check by doing something like this?

```
show:  ( overrides && overrides.show ? overrides.show : showFoo ),
hide:  ( overrides && overrides.hide ? overrides.hide : hideFoo ),
// ...
```

Comment: Generally speaking, I think you're right about not needing to check against null - however it can be not-null and false then it would evaluate to false (though in this case I think that'd be ok)

Comment: Overrides.show looks like it could be a boolean; if so, you'd need to test it against null explicitly.

Comment: @Fred the intention is to pass functions for show, hide and commit.  If a false is passed there then showFoo() will be used.  If a true is passed there then that'll be passed in place of showFoo() and cause trouble further down so I guess I need to tread carefully there.  Having said that though, I'll only ever be passing a function in those parameters so I'll probably survive for now.

Comment: Might be worth pointing out that this use of `&&` is only valid as long as `&&` is a short-circuiting `and` operation (which is a safe assumption for C-derived languages, but not all languages).

Comment: Can be even shorter: `show: overrides && overrides.show || showFoo`

Answer (score 3):

In JavaScript, you are not required to explicitly check if a variable is null or undefined because:

1. null or undefined return false in a boolean expression.
2. JS expressions are evaluated from left to right. So for `a || b`, if `a` is false, then only `b` will be evaluated. But if `a` is true, `b` will not be checked. Similarly for `a && b` if `a` is false, `b` will not be evaluated.

Hence, `if (a != null) { "do something" }` can be written as `if (a) { "do something" }` or simply `a && "do something"`.

In the same way it can be used to set a default value when the value is set to null or undefined:

```
function someFunction(age){
    :
    var age= age|| 18;
    :
}
```

`someFunction(28)` results in 28 whereas `someFunction()` results in 18.