# Cleaning up a three-factor if statement

Tags: c#

A method that I'm working on in a C# project includes the following:

```
if (isDailyRateRequired) 
{
    CalculatedDailyRate = dailyRate;
}

if (isWeeklyRateRequired) 
{
    CalculatedDailyRate = weeklyRate / 7;
}

if (isMonthlyRateRequired) 
{
    CalculatedDailyRate = monthlyRate / 30;
}
```

There has to be a cleaner implementation than this. I could compress it to one line with a set of nested ternary operators, but that would be pretty much unreadable.

Other suggestions?

Comment: *I could compress it to one line with a set of nested ternary operators, but that would be pretty much unreadable.* - Not necessarily.  Please see my answer for a [similar question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/6544/ternary-operation-java-isnt-this-abuse/6562#6562).

Comment: Show the code please where the boolean variables is set I mean isDailyRateRequired etc. Show more code or explain what you want to do at all. I think it is need to redesign not only this method with if statements.

Answer (score 12):

By looking at your code it appears to me that your basic problem is that `isDailyRateRequired`, `isWeeklyRateRequired` and `isMonthlyRateRequired` are distinct boolean variables instead of an `enum`.  If you just turned them all into an enum things would be a lot more simple, there would be no possibility of inconsistencies between their values, and you would not even have this multiple-choice issue.

Comment: Good thought. However, these values are coming out of a `DataSet` and are stored as three columns in a database. Did I mention I'm working on a legacy app? :)

Comment: @JoshEarl - yikes! Perhaps you could [add a calculated column to your DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810291.aspx). You could use [the IFF function in the expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(v=vs.71).aspx) in order to convert those 3 boolean values into a single Enum value, or you could define the expression to derive the correct rate directly.

Answer (score 8):

Since those seem to be mutually exclusive conditions, you may not want to execute all 3 `if`s every time by putting an `else` in between:

```
if (isDailyRateRequired) 
{
    CalculatedDailyRate = dailyRate;
}
else if (isWeeklyRateRequired) 
{
    CalculatedDailyRate = weeklyRate / 7;
}
else if (isMonthlyRateRequired) 
{
    CalculatedDailyRate = monthlyRate / 30;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If these conditions are exclusive conditions you should not use booleans. 
Use an enumeration with three named constants (or states): `DailyRate`, `WeeklyRate` and `MonthlyRate`.
 It prevents invalid states where more than one (or zero) boolean are `true`. (As @MikeNakis already suggested.)

If these three `if` statements repeating in the code replace the conditional with polymorphism. (See *Replacing the Conditional Logic on Price Code with Polymorphism* in *Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing Code* by *Martin Fowler*).

Since these booleans comes from a legacy database maybe you want to throw an exception or at least log an error message when more than one (or zero) flags are `true`.

Answer (score 3):

How about adding a [calculated column to your DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810291.aspx)?

The [expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) is not exactly simpler, but doing it this way might provide it's own advantages:

```
new System.Data.DataColumn("CalculatedDailyRate", typeof(decimal), "IIF(isDailyRateRequired, dailyRate, IIF(isWeeklyRateRequired, weeklyRate / 7, IIF(isMonthlyRateRequired, monthlyRate / 30, null)))")
```

Multi-line version that might be easier to read:

```
        new System.Data.DataColumn("CalculatedDailyRate", typeof(decimal), @"
            IIF(isDailyRateRequired, dailyRate,
            IIF(isWeeklyRateRequired, weeklyRate / 7,
            IIF(isMonthlyRateRequired, monthlyRate / 30,
            null)))")
```

Comment: This hides the messiness inside the thing that's causing the messiness. :) Kinda liking this option. The only downside is that it seems like it might be hard to find later. We have a ~1 million line codebase, so discoverability is a consideration.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a class `Interval` with subclasses `DailyInterval`, `WeeklyInterval`, and `MonthlyInterval` and then do:

```
interval = isDailyRateRequired? new DailyInterval(dailyRate):
           isWeeklyRateRequired? new WeeklyInterval(weeklyRate):
           isMonthlyRateRequired? new MonthlyInterval(monthlyRate):
           /* throw exception */;

calculatedDailyRate = interval.DailyRate();
```

...where the method `DailyRate()` automatically returns the appropriate rate based on the internally-known interval duration.

Of course, this only makes sense if you'll be using intervals in lots of places.