# Multiple returns in a method or one return

Tags: javascript

I have a method which returns an Array. This array can contain values or can be empty. Here is the code:

```
function getCustomerIds() {
    //this declaration is at the top to inform about returning value of the method; I don't declare variables at the top
    var customerIds = [];
    var linkedContact = getLinkedContacts(this);
    if (linkedContact === null) {
        return [];
    }
    var linkedResource = getLinkedResources(linkedContact);
    if (linkedResource === null) {
        return [];
    }
    var linkedCustomersIds = getLinkedCustomers(linkedResource);
    return customerIds.concat(linkedCustomersIds);
}
```

I'm not sure if it should be `return []` or `return customerIds`. The first one seems more explicit that the empty array is returned, while the second option seems more logical. What would be the best practice here?  Do you have some other suggestions re method structure?

Comment: Why does the `customerIds` variable exists at all?

Comment: It's purpose is to inform about returning value of the method.

Comment: What does `getLinkedResources` and `getLinkedContacts` do? Also, I believe the last line is supposted to be `concat`, I've never heard of a `contat` function.

Comment: They return IDs of objects. At the current case assume they return only one ID. You're right about `concat` function, it's a typo

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg There is a subtle difference between returning the result of `getLinkedCustomers()` directly and returning a copy of it. This code does the latter.

Comment: In JS, you never need to check if a value is null or undefined see my [this](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/43772/38328) answer

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's debatable. Or perhaps I'd say: it's very dependent on context.

If you return early (as you do here), I think it's probably good to return `[]`. When you read the code, you see the conditional and its effect: an empty array is returned, period. To me early returns feel a bit like throwing exceptions - not in the sense that there's an error, but just "this is a special case; do something special and return control to the caller (i.e. exit the function)"

The other way to go about it is, of course, to return at the end of the function, and treat the steps before that as optional (or "conditional" to be exact). They *may* do something to the `customerIds` array, or they may not. Regardless, we return the array at the end, whether it's empty or not.

(note: I'm using all these words, like "normal" or "special", *very* lightly. Don't read too much into them)

Either way is perfectly acceptable, so it's pretty much up to you. You've got two dependent conditionals, so returning early is a good way to avoid a ton of indentation and nesting.

However, if the return value "changes" when the function returns early, and you don't otherwise declare variables at the top, I'd skip declaring `customerIds` there too. If the idea is to declare the thing you'll return, but then you don't return that specific object anyway, it's misdirection. Though again, this is really on the margins of "does it matter?" because you're always returning an array, so it's not like the var declaration is totally false.

But, but, in your case, the simplest solution might be to not have that declaration at all. If you expect the code to be read, and people to see the `return [];`, you can also expect them to read to the end of the function anyway, and see what it would otherwise return. No need for the return-type pseudo-declaration at all. <strike>Especially as it's not needed at all (the `concat` call is pointless).</strike> (see update below the code)

```
function getCustomerIds() {
    var linkedContact = getLinkedContacts(this);
    if (linkedContact === null) {
        return [];
    }
    var linkedResource = getLinkedResources(linkedContact);
    if (linkedResource === null) {
        return [];
    }
    return getLinkedCustomers(linkedResource);
}
```

*Update:* As 200_success points out in the comments, the semantics *do* change when returning without using `concat`. However, I'd probably still prefer a more direct route than declaring an empty array (that I might not use for anything), and using `concat`. I'd probably do this

```
return getLinkedCustomers(linkedResource).slice(0);
```

to get a copy of the array returned by `getLinkedCustomers()`. *End of update*

No declaration necessary. Your function's name (which is plural) should already be a strong enough hint that an array will get returned. Or, you know, add a comment... that's a pretty good way to deal with this too, now that I think about it.

So basically, I think it's your custom of "kinda' sorta'" declaring the return type that's interfering here. Since such a declaration is not exactly binding or enforced by JS (at all), the early returns muddy the picture.

Or (for fun) if you just want to confuse people for a moment :)

```
function getCustomerIds() {
    var linkedContact = getLinkedContacts(this),
        linkedResource = !linkedContact || getLinkedResources(linkedContact);
    return linkedResource ? getLinkedCustomers(linkedResource) : [];
}
```

---

Update: If I'm correct in assuming that *all* the `getLinked...()` functions return similar types, then we can deduce that they all return either an array or `null`.

If that's the case, then both my suggestion (not the joking one above, but the actual one higher up), and your code may give some unexpected results.

The original `customerIds.concat(linkedCustomersIds)` will result in `[null]` - *not* an empty array.

My code will either return the `null` directly, or - if you use the `slice` call - it'll just fail, as `null` doesn't have a `slice` function.

So there should perhaps be a 3rd conditional for `null`-checking the return of `getLinkedCustomers(linkedResource)` and deciding what to return.

But again, this is me making some straight-up guesses at how the rest of the code works. No idea if it's actually an issue.

However, it's confusing that your variables are *singular*, but hold the return values of functions that are *plural*. Given the plural function names, I'd assume the return values are (nominally) arrays, but given the singular variables, I'd assume something else (anything else, really).

Comment: Be aware, though, that returning the result of `getLinkedCustomers()` directly instead of returning a copy is semantically different from the original code.

Comment: @200_success True. It's an assumption on my part (I'll make that clear - thanks for pointing it out). But I'd probably go for duplicating the array from `getLinkedCustomers` rather than using `concat`.

Answer (score 6):

You should `return` when you're ready to `return` and no later (or sooner).

When I see a `return` statement I know immediately that the processing has finished for that logical branch. If you wait to return until the bottom of the function, then I need to do more (unnecessary) reasoning about (what will ultimately be) the return value. Does it get modified later? Does its present value trigger some other function or side-effect below? I don't know.

Also, I agree that `return []` is more explicit and therefore preferable. Again, why make me reason unnecessarily about what's being returned there? If it can only ever be an empty array, then *make that obvious*.

Answer (score 4):

While I'm fine with multiple returns for longer methods or throwing exceptions from guard clauses, I would probably rewrite the code as below. I find it easier to think of the method as "get the customer IDs if there are any, otherwise return an empty array."

```
function getCustomerIds() {
    var contact, resource;
    return (contact = getLinkedContacts(this)) && (resource = getLinkedResources(contact))
        ? getLinkedCustomers(resource) : [];
}
```

And I would definitely have `getLinkedCustomers` return a copy of the array of IDs rather than have callers copy it themselves.

Comment: I would rather maintain the original code than this. If it wasn't for the excellent observation that `getLinkedCustomers` should provide a copy, I would -1 this.

Answer (score 3):

And now for something completely different. You could completely bypass the question and simplify the API by employing two [Null Objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern): one each for an empty set of contacts and resources.

```
SomeObject.prototype.getCustomerIds = function () {
    return this.getLinkedContacts().getLinkedResources().getLinkedCustomers();
};

SomeObject.prototype.getLinkedContacts = function () {
    if (this.linkedContacts.length === 0) {
        return new NoContacts();
    }
    else { ... }
};

NoContacts.prototype.getLinkedResources = function () {
    return new NoResources();
};

NoResources.prototype.getLinkedCustomers = function () {
    return [];
};
```

Answer (score 2):

### Re @Flambino's second suggestion

`0` is falsy. But it is usually a valid key/index. Therefore using expressions like `!linkedContact` and `linkedResource ? ... : ...` which depend on `null` being falsy in **chain lookups** gets you in trouble.
Also note two expressions are not consistent in style. Another readability problem is multiple declarations in single statement.

But these could be fixed as below, to yield a valid alternative:

```
var linkedContact = getLinkedContacts(this);
var linkedResource = linkedContact === null ? null : getLinkedResources(linkedContact);
var linkedCustomersIds = linkedResource === null ? null : getLinkedCustomers(linkedResource);
return linkedCustomersId === null ? [] : linkedCustomersIds;
```

Comment: I thought I made it fairly clear that that code was a joke. But your points are of course valid, just kinda meta since you're basically reviewing _my_ code and not OP's :P

Comment: @Flambino I've seen David's answer, which made the same mistake, after I posted mine and now believe more firmly that this is a useful answer. About your suggestion being a joke: humans remember patterns, and they reproduce them. You shouldn't *show* them what **not** to do. (Editing your joke would be too presumptuous.)

Answer (score 2):

I believe that multiple returns (accompanied by proper comments, which is optional) will help you to have code with a fewer number of opening and closing brackets used.

It happens especially when there are many condition checks or complex requirements.